# tweet specific blog post link not working

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code for readers to be able to tweet a specific blog post-

```
<a expr:href='"http://twitter.com/home?status=Reading " + data:post.title + " @mytwitter " + data:post.url' class='twitter'></a>

.content .share .social ul li a.twitter {
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background: url(img/twitter.png);
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.content .share .social ul li a.twitter:hover {
    background: url(img/twitter-hover.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

The link isn't working, and doesn't even appear to be active and I'm not quite sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the javascript associated with this code?

Comment: There are many plugins that can accomplish this without modifying your core WP files, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would do your hyperlink this way instead since you are doing it from JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var twitterURI = "http://twitter.com/home?status=Reading " + data:post.title + " @mytwitter " + data:post.url;
document.write('<a expr:href="' + twitterURI + '"></a>');
</script>
```

Here is a Bit.ly snippet of code you can reference from as well if you dont want to wrap it inside the script tags

```
<a href="javascript:var e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('language','javascript');e.setAttribute('src','http://bit.ly/bookmarklet/load.js?utm_source=publisher-sidebar&ls=0&u='+encodeURIComponent('<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>'));document.body.appendChild(e);void(0);">Share with Bit.ly Sidebar</a>
```

Comment: This makes sense. I'm curious though, the image is being pulled from CSS by using `class="twitter"`. What is the best way to implement that in this particular bit of code?

Comment: Personally inside the link I would do a <a href="httplink"><div class="twitter"></div> Follow us!</a> with some text so that you have something that is separating the class by using a div with the actual link.